# Launch4J not picking up bundled JRE

Tags: launch4j

i am aware that there are many similar questions like this one, but i could not make it work with those solutions.

I am using Launch4J 3.50, and trying to run a exe using a bundled JRE, which is provided by adoptium https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=11

By starting the exe from a bat file, using SET Launch4j=debug option, i am able to generate this log file:

```
Version:    3.50
CmdLine:    D:\MyApp.exe 
JNI:        No
WOW64:      Yes
Working dir:    D:\.
Requires JDK:   Yes
Requires 64-Bit: No
Java min ver:   1.011.000_000
Java max ver:   1.011.900_900
JRE paths:  service\adoptium
Check launcher: D:\service\adoptium\bin\javaw.exe (OK)
Check javac:    D:\service\adoptium\bin\javac.exe (not found)
64-bit search:  SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit...
32-bit search:  SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit...
64-bit search:  SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK...
32-bit search:  SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK...
64-bit search:  SOFTWARE\IBM\Java Development Kit...
32-bit search:  SOFTWARE\IBM\Java Development Kit...
64-bit search:  SOFTWARE\IBM\Java Development Kit...
32-bit search:  SOFTWARE\IBM\Java Development Kit...
Error msg:  This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 11.0.0 - 11.900.900
```

This is my root folder:

[image]

This is my service folder:

[image]

And this is my Launch4J xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>C:\Users\jhonnyD\Desktop\launch4j\service\jars\MyApp.jar</jar>
  <outfile>.\MyApp.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir>.</chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl></downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon>C:\Users\jhonnyD\Desktop\launch4j\myIcon.ico</icon>
  <classPath>
    <mainClass>com.main.StartMyApp</mainClass>
    <cp>C:\Users\jhonnyD\Desktop\launch4j\service\jars\lib\*</cp>
  </classPath>
  <jre>
    <path>service/adoptium</path>
    <requiresJdk>true</requiresJdk>
    <requires64Bit>false</requires64Bit>
    <minVersion>11.0.0</minVersion>
    <maxVersion>11.900.900</maxVersion>
  </jre>
</launch4jConfig>
```

When i run this on a computer that has java installed, the exe works. Clearly it is picking up the jre from the system. When i run this on a computer where java is missing, i am getting:

```
This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 11.0.0 - 11.900.900
```

The strange thing is that the log states that bundled javaw.exe is found:

```
Check launcher: D:\service\adoptium\bin\javaw.exe (OK)
```

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to change the option in tag `<requiresJdk>` from `true` to `false`.
I've tested launch4j 3.50 just now on my app with similar config and it worked fine with this min config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>C:\launch4j-3.50-win32\service\jars\dvm.jar</jar>
  <outfile>C:\launch4j-3.50-win32\dvm.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir>.</chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl></downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon></icon>
  <jre>
    <path>service/adoptium</path>
    <requiresJdk>false</requiresJdk>
    <requires64Bit>false</requires64Bit>
    <minVersion></minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
  </jre>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. Could you post the snippet of maven plugin that worked for you?

Comment: I've edited the answer, because it's too long for the comment. With this configuration it compiles the exe file for my app and it works fine. But it is Swing gui app

Comment: :( i tried this approach. The exe does not pick up the bundled JRE. Can you please try my configuration on your computer WITHOUT having java installed?

Comment: Can you try please to use not JRE, but JDK? I see the error about compiler. Or try to change property <requiresJdk>true</requiresJdk> from true to false. As for me, I've tried just now and it worked with min config, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: You are right. By setting requiresJdk = false the exe starts by picking up the bundled JRE. For some reason i thought that option was refering to the bundled JRE, not to the installed one, installed on host. Can you change your answer to just point out  requiresJdk = true was wrong? I will accept

Comment: Done  and deleted the unnecessary text